# JavaFX or Swing in a new project

Tags: swing, javafx

Well, i have 180 days to construct a new project, where i should use the TOP tecnologies (Java 8, Hibernate 5 and more ..)

I have a big doubt before start it: What GUI Framework should i use ?

If i should use Swing (as i always did) or start this project with JavaFX ( i don't have any knowledge about it).

So, i'm thinking about some things:

1) If i start with JavaFX, the difference will be very big to customer ?
2) If i start with JavaFX, in 180 days i will have enought time to study about this tecnology ? Is very complex or different from Swing?

Comment: I understand that Swing have Much more support than javaFx in this moment

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on your project. The elements required to cover the needs of this, (*graphics components / design / logic*), in terms of unlimited design (CSS) and logic (FXML / Java), `JavaFX` prevails but with a slight delay on the graphics components on, (**in my humble opinion**), an indispenable component (**RichText**) which can be overtaken by a few open projects ,i think the only `Swing`advantage is its  wide community, **this is just a simple personal opinion** !

Comment: I Think that wide community is not a simple detail but a big detail, this make all difference

Comment: I did not say *simple detail*, I said *the only advantage*, But we can't deny the robustness of `JavaFX` just because of his community or it's difficult to apprehend, but in your case the time factor does not leave you the choice even if there is not a large difference between the two, it all depends on your abilities good luck !